# WebClient DownloadString UTF-8 not displaying international characters

Tags: c#, html, encoding, utf-8, webclient

I attempt to save the html of a website in a string. The website has international characters (ę, ś, ć, ...) and they are not being saved to the string even though I set the encoding to be UTF-8 which corresponds to the websites charset.

Here is my code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.filmweb.pl/Mroczne.Widmo");
}
```

When I print "htmlCode" to the console, the international characters are not shown correctly even though in the original HTML they are shown correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that `client.DownloadString` doesn’t encode the characters using UTF-8. Using `client.DownloadData` and encoding the returned data with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` solve the problem.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     var htmlData = client.DownloadData("http://www.filmweb.pl/Mroczne.Widmo");
     var htmlCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(htmlData);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this still does not work for me. It seems that even a simple string specialChar = "ĉ" does not work either, so I'm suspecting it is a problem with the string? I don't know much about encoding but thank you for the answer nonetheless
--EDIT-- I think it is my printing methods, I will get back to you as this might be the correct answer you gave me.

Comment: Yup, that totally worked, thank you! I was just going off of the console output when in the form it was displaying correctly. Weird. Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it the hard way.
There is an `Encoding` property on the `WebClient`, which can be set to `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The OP is trying that in the question already.