# Webclient encoding for DownloadString

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program to translate CSV files using google translate. This is my code:

```
Dim sURL As String
    Dim oWebClient As New WebClient
    Dim sResult As String

    oWebClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII

    If Not IsNothing(sTo) Then
        ' Construct URL
        sURL = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", sString, sFrom & "|" & sTo)
        sResult = oWebClient.DownloadString(sURL)

        sResult = sResult.Substring(sResult.IndexOf("TRANSLATED_TEXT="))
        sResult = sResult.Substring(0, sResult.IndexOf(";"))

        ' Get the string between the '' after Translated Text
        sResult = sResult.Substring(sResult.IndexOf("'") + 1, sResult.Count - 18)
    Else
        sResult = ""
    End If
```

Now I'm trying to translate to french, but the given result does not hold accents. For example Rejeté becomes: 'Rejet?'. The string in sResult literally holds "TRANSLATED_TEXT='Rejet?'".

Did some googling around and at first I encoded my webclient as UTF-8 and found out ASCII should be better because ASCII actually has these characters. However ASCII also doesn't work.

I've been trying to figure out if HttpUtility can help me, but I don't really understand how it works. [HttpUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

Anyone with some insights?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is a screenshot of the html visualizer of my result, the downloaddata method gives the same result as downloadstring.
[HTML Visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Gwj.png)

EDIT2: I almost solved it! Using Tom's link and adjusting the encoding to:

```
            sResult = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(oWebClient.DownloadData(sURL))
```

Got me closer, Rejeté now actually comes out. But for some reason
D'accord comes out as D\x26#3.
Anyone any idea?

Comment: No, ASCII does not. The HTTP server should tell which character encoding the text is written with in the Content-Type header. `DownloadString` is not all that useful because it doesn't read the Content-Type header for that purpose. You could try to set a different encoding in advance but a server is free to choose an encoding for any response so that's a fragile solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebClient DownloadString UTF-8 not displaying international characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200465/webclient-downloadstring-utf-8-not-displaying-international-characters)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, tried it, without any results...
Tried the method with UTF-8 and ASCII, just for good measures. The only difference this makes is that the '?' in UTF-8 is in a black box. In ASCII this is just a normal '?' 
The download data method however shows me the header and the header tells me the site is encoded in ISO-8859-1, however I can't choose this in my encoding.